# dc.js reselect a chart already rendered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, dc.js

I am trying to manually re-set the width of an already rendered pie chart. The chart is created and rendered in a angular factory and directive, and I would like to get at this chart from a controller. Is there a select method akin to

```
var chart = dc.pieChart("#pieChart");
```

that I can use to be able to this type of thing

```
chart
   .width(500)

dc.redrawAll()
```

how can I re-select a chart that is already rendered in order to do the above?

so I just passed the chart object back through a custom object on the scope just to try to get at it and it works.

```
// inside something else
$scope.thisObject.charts.forEach(function(d){
    if (d.name === element.id) {
         // found the right object
         d.chart
            .width(500)
            .height(500)

         dc.chart.render();
         // this works for bars, rows and line charts, but not pies?
    }
})
```

Comment: I think you'll have to hold onto the chart object somehow. I don't know how angular works but it's annoying if it would hide this from you. You could also poke around in the [chart registry](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.chartRegistry.html) but I'm not sure how you would compare charts to find the right one.

Comment: hmmm...thanks Gordon. I will see if I can pass the chart object back through a custom object and get at it that way.

Comment: yeah no go on that, it changes the dimensions (height, wid) of the svg, but even with renderAll and redrawAll it doesn't increase the g/path, etc

Comment: it works for bars, rows and lines but not pie charts? any ideas?

Comment: Gee, I'd hate to see you using `renderAll`, that starts from absolute zero. It should work with a redraw. [This example demonstrates resizing a pie chart and redrawing it.](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/resizing/resizing-pie.html) (Resize the browser window to try it.) Could it be something simple like the radius being defined when it should just be calculated from the width/height?

Comment: so after I get that chart object back through a property ref on another one it seems to work fine, even with  d.chart.render(), but for whatever reason I haven't been able to get the pies to resize? not sure...I am only specifying .width(600) and .height(600) then calling render? probably something else hokey in here.

Comment: Yeah that's why I asked if maybe you're setting the radius manually? Resize should work as long as the radius is _not_ set. And _please_ redraw, don't render, if it works it will look a lot nicer.

Answer (score 0):

Try [dc.redrawAll](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#dcredrawallgroup) after changing chart width like,

```
dc.redrawAll();
```

Hope it works, otherwise you can go with another option [dc.renderAll()](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#dcrenderallgroup)

Comment: thanks, but this wasn't my question. I am wondering how I can "select" a chart that is already rendered... so that I can manually "re-set" the properties (width, etc).